# Drawing real part of reciprocal of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to draw the complex numbers with following attributes:

$$\Re\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=c $$

for $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

I really lack any intuition for this problem and I hope someone could help.

Thank you.

Comment: $$\frac1{a+bi}=\frac a{a^2+b^2}-\frac{bi}{a^2+b^2}$$

Comment: Geometric hint worth pursuing: the map $z \to 1/z$ is an inversion. It turns (circles and lines) into (circles and lines).